# command line pop3 mail client for windows?

Tags: windows, email, command-line-interface

Does anyone know of a client that I can use to access a pop3 mailbox via command line on windows? I need it to support downloading emails to a file and have SSL support. I would really like for it to be free too. Using my google-fu, I wasn't able to find an app that had all 3 of those features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this site http://www.blat.net/194/

We use Blat for sending mail via command line and are very happy with it.  The link has alot of info.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something to receive mail not send it.

Comment: My bad...but I think the link may mention GetMail for Windows.  Its a cmd tool to automatically get mail...works only with Win.

Comment: Wow, getmail was what I was looking for. The reason getmail is good and the above suggestions did not work for me is because getmail has a headers-only download, which helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome...hope it works out.  I have found so many solutions to my daily problems here!  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Does it really support SSL? It's not even mentioned anywhere in manual! @cop1152

Answer (score 6):

No SSL support, but i use it when i need to:

```
c:\>telnet pop3.stackoverflow.com 110
   +OK Hello there.
   >user iboyd
   +OK Password required.
   >pass correct horse battery staple
   +OK Logged in.
   >list
   +OK
   1 1924
   2 1915
   .
   >retr 1
   Receive: from localhost ....
   [trim]
   >dele 1
   +OK Deleted
   >quit
   +OK Bye-bye.

Connection to host lost.

C:\>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Command Line Pop Client](http://www.codeode.com/popclient/index.html) in combination with the SSL wrapper [Stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/).

**Command Line Pop Client**

> Command Line POP Client is a free
>   console utility that allows you to
>   receive your e-mails to a local
>   directory. It is suitable for batch
>   jobs or whenever there is a need to
>   download e-mails as files into a
>   folder. This mail receiver supports
>   the POP3 protocol and is both robust
>   and light weight. The settings are
>   defined in an xml file.
>
> This e-mail client is compatible for
>   Windows 95, 98, Me, NT, 2000, XP and
>   2003.

**Stunnel**

> Stunnel is a program that allows you
>   to encrypt arbitrary TCP connections
>   inside SSL (Secure Sockets Layer)
>   available on both Unix and Windows.
>   Stunnel can allow you to secure
>   non-SSL aware daemons and protocols
>   (like POP, IMAP, LDAP, etc) by having
>   Stunnel provide the encryption,
>   requiring no changes to the daemon's
>   code.
>
> The Stunnel source code is not a
>   complete product -- you still require
>   a functioning SSL library such as
>   OpenSSL or SSLeay in order to compile
>   stunnel. This means that stunnel can
>   support whatever (and only) that which
>   your SSL library can, without making
>   any changes in the Stunnel code.

Answer (score 1):

you could use pine via cygwin; I've used that before.

Answer (score 0):

You could use these cmdlets for Powershell

http://www.nsoftware.com/powershell/

These are not free, however

Answer (score 0):

Heres one.. http://www.codeode.com/popclient/index.html

Comment: Doesn't look like it supports SSL

Comment: Indeed, it does not. That was one of them I tried.

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't necessarily need a command line client: I just managed to install, configure and exec Thunderbird as a Windows service and configure it to store attachments of mails in some directory using filters. This has the benefit of a fully fledged POP3 client with automatic updates, support of modern TLS etc. as long as Thunderbird gets maintained at all. Using the GUI, one is easily able to configure filters and stuff as needed.

Simply install Thunderbird using default settings. Start it interactively and install an AddOn named [FiltaQuilla](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/), which allows to store attachments of mails. Once confiugured as needed, Thundebird can be configured to exec as Windows service easily by using [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/usage). That is even capable of sending WM-messages to properly close Thunderbird's windows when shutting down.

I've tested that setup by restarting Windows, sending test mails and their attachments have been stored at a time when is was NOT yet logged in interactively. As NSSM integrates with Windows Events, some kind of monitoring is possible as well. The following are some example error messages when things didn't work yet properly:

> Service test_thunderbird_nssm action for exit code 0 is Restart. Attempting to restart C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe.